# how to pagination work in gridview.builder with other widget flutter

Tags: flutter, pagination

this my code on main page, pagination not work.
[this my main code with other widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXXdg.png)

but I make new page without other widget, pagination worked

[same code but without other widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWrHv.png)

i need pagination work in main page with other widget carousel etc.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.